# SMTP Cpanel giving error smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550)

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

I am trying to send email using python based on the email id I generated  via Cpanel for my domain

```
import smtplib
with smtplib.SMTP('mail.rottengrapes.com',587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    # smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.login("formkitty@rottengrapes.com",config.PASSWORD)
    subject = 'Testing email'
    body = 'Getting data via email'
    msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n\n\n{body}'
    smtp.sendmail("formkitty@rottengrapes.com",'mewow@gmail.com', msg)
    print('printed')
```

I'm getting the following error

> raise SMTPDataError(code, resp) smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, b'Your
> FROM address ( rottengrapes.com ,  ) must match your
> authenticated\nemail domain ( rottengrapes.com ). Treating this as a
> spoofed email.')

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue?